# HTML Forms Sharing Unwanted Input Values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having a very frustrating form/input problem and I am using ReactJS. Basically I am dynamically rendering one form or another, but when input is entered into an input element, that value is somehow shared with the other form too.

To further explain, picture Form1 with Input1A and Input1B, and Form2 with Input2A and Input2B. If I enter "hello" into Input1A then switch to display Form2, Input2A will also have "hello" in it. Here is the code:

```
<Fragment>
  {selectedAuth === "register" ? (
    <form
      className={styles.form}
      onSubmit={this.registerHandler}
      name="regForm"
    >
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Full Name"
        id="regName"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler}
      />
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email Address"
        id="regEmail"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler}
     />
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="tel"
        placeholder="Phone Number"
        id="regPhone"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler}
     />
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        id="regPasswordOne"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler} 
      />
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Re-enter Password"
        id="regPasswordTwo"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler}      
      />
      <button className={styles.submitButton} type="submit">
        Register
      </button>
    </form>
  ) : (
    <form
      className={styles.form}
      onSubmit={this.loginHandler}
      name="loginForm"
    >
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email Address"
        id="loginEmail"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler}
      />
      <input
        styles={inputStyle}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        id="loginPassword"
        onChange={this.formFieldInputHandler}
      />
      <button className={styles.submitButton} type="submit">
        Log In
      </button>
    </form>
  )}
</Fragment>
```

Here is `formFieldInputHandler`:

```
  formFieldInputHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT: Figured it out here, copy pasting my answer**
This has to do with how React re-renders components and reconciliation. Take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

All I needed to do was add a different "key" property to my forms so now it looks like:

```
<form
    className={styles.form}
    onSubmit={this.registerHandler}
    key="regForm"
/>
```

and

```
<form
    className={styles.form}
    onSubmit={this.loginHandler}
    key="loginForm"
/>
```

Comment: I don't see you binding form element values with the state, wondering how its showing you values in textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out literally 2 seconds after posting. This has to do with how React re-renders components and reconciliation. Take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

All I needed to do was add a different "key" property to my forms so now it looks like:

```
<form
  className={styles.form}
  onSubmit={this.registerHandler}
  key="regForm"
/>
```

and

```
<form
  className={styles.form}
  onSubmit={this.loginHandler}
  key="loginForm"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't bind your function `formFieldInputHandler`
[react event doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
[bind doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

So you need to call something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // ...
  this.formFieldInputHandler = this.formFieldInputHandler.bind(this);
}
```

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am using the relevant bable transpilers, so I dont need to bind my handlers while using arrow functions!